# What is recommended size of an android application?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, size

I am developing an android application in which I want to embed database in the app itself. The app is about farmers where database is related to the information about various crops, fertilizers, herbicides, irrigation methods etc(around 40-50 rows with 7-8 columns). I haven't worked with SQLITE database so I don't know how much will be the size of data. So, can anyone tell me what will be the size of database and will my app be too large or of recommended size?

Comment: If your app will be serving end-users using cell phones, considering using a web-server to manage data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you're working with massive data sets (millions of rows) or you're using a lot of image resources, you'll be fine.

I'm guessing the recommended size is under 20MB. Yours will easily be under 10MB unless you do something really strange.

Comment: Thanx Geoff.. That helps a lot. Can you tell me what will be the approx size of the database file that I will be embedding in assets folder?

Comment: It can vary wildly. I'd suggest using an sqllite editor of some description to create a database and enter fake fields. You can work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play does have an .apk upload limit of 50mb so try to work under that. If your app has not many other resources besides the database file, it'll be quite simple for you to track and control your app size.

If, somehow, you do exceed the 50mb limit, Google does support expansion files.
[image]

Hope this helps :)